# how to add jde components plugin in an eclipse

Tags: javascript, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I need to add jde component plugin in an blackberry eclipse.I have already used the following link in my eclipse:

http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.5/java

But am getting the error as:
'installing software' has encountered a problem.An error occurred while collecting items to be installed.

Please tell me the solution.

Answer (score 2):

That happened with me so many times that I stopped using that update site. Instead, try downloading the component package directly from:

http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javadevenv.jsp

Answer (score 1):

The answer may be simple: Perhaps Windows installs it's updates (and only one installation process can be run at one time), or some other installations or processes may interrupting you.

Try just restart you system and retry your installation.